# How to Register CustomContext(DbConnection connection, DbCompiledModel compiledModel) with SimpleInjector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, simple-injector

My CustomContext Looks like below.

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomContext(DbConnection connection, DbCompiledModel compiledModel) : base(connection, compiledModel, true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CustomContext>(null);
    }
    //Other methods go here
}
```

My registration of services looks like below

```
_container = new Container();
_container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
RegisterTypes(_container);
```

RegisterTypes method

```
private static void RegisterTypes(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterSingleton<IMapper>(() =>
    {
        var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
        }));
        #if DEBUG
        mapper.DefaultContext.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        #endif
        return mapper;
    });

    container.Register(() => new AutoMapperConfiguration(),
        Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IUoWFactory, DbUoWFactory>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IRepository, DbRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ICartonDetailService, CartonDetailService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnection"];
    container.Register<DbConnection>(() => new OracleConnection(connectionString),
            Lifestyle.Singleton);
    container.Register<DbCompiledModel>();
    container.Register(() => new CustomContext(container.GetInstance<DbConnection>(), container.GetInstance<DbCompiledModel>()),
        Lifestyle.Scoped);

    container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
}
```

The problem is DbCompiledModel does not have any Constructor and hence the I cannot register DbCompiledModel and CustomContext as in above. Please help me solve this.

Update:
Changed the constructor of CustomContext as below

```
ShamrockContext(DbConnection connection, Type[] types, ISfcInMemoryCache cache) : base(connection, cache.GetValue<DbCompiledModel>(types), false)
```

`cache.GetValue` returns the cached DbCompiledModel by reading the Model list from types. The problem now is that it throws error on Type[]. Is there a way I can pass runtime parameters to these constructors.

Comment: What requirement do you have that leads you to having this specific DbContext constructor? Would another constructor do? For instance one that accepts a connection string?

Comment: Each service will know what Models to use, these types will be compiled, cached and passed on to DbContext. The context will only have access to these Models.

Comment: And why do you use a singleton DbConnection. You are aware that connections are not thread safe?

Comment: Are you sure `types` is runtime data - it sounds like something you would know at design time?

Comment: They are not really run time types. Each service knows what Models to use.

Comment: Check out [Context-based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection)